# Recover an accidently deleted post

Tags: support, deleted-posts

How do I recover a post which I accidentally deleted? I deleted my previous post on Photoshop by mistake!

Comment: Looks like it's undeleted now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347419/transform-action-in-photoshop-cs5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess this is your question (only 10k+ users can see at the moment):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347419/transform-action-in-photoshop-cs5

To recover that:

1. ask moderators by flagging one of your posts and explain in the "requires moderator attention" option, OR
2. to undelete yourself

   1. go to [this dummy question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/85)
   2. paste the following in the address bar

      ```
      javascript:$.post("/posts/5347419/vote/11",{fkey:$("#fkey").val()})
      ```

      instead of `$("#fkey").val()`, `StackExchange.options.user.fkey` might be preferable.

Comment: 10k users and the OP should be able to see it, and the OP should be able to one click undelete, if they were the one to delete it in the first place (and this is the case here, so Amrish should be able to see it and undelete it).

Comment: @Adam Davis, definitely agree.

Comment: that script was an amazing fix. Thanks!!

Comment: +1 Script helped me very much. Thanks a lot. One of my chrome extension was throwing JavaScript error and I was not able to click `undelete`. Refreshing the page would display page not found and then I would have never been able to undelete it unless I knew the post Id and the above script.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the post, and find the `undelete` link immediately below it.  It should be in the same place that the delete link you clicked on was.

Click `undelete` and you should be fine.

The post is still visible to you if you know the link to it, but it won't show up on your user page or activity page.  It may still be in your browser cache, though, try typing a portion of the title into your address bar to see if your browser remembers it, or look through your browser history.  Once you find the URL, you can go to it, and undelete it.

If you still can't find the post, flag another of your posts for moderator attention, and request that they help you find the post you recently deleted, and undelete it for you.

Comment: "Go to the post" But what if you've lost track of it?