# How do I recover my unposted draft message if my computer crashes before I've posted it?

Tags: support

AFAIK, my question is different from [Recover an accidently deleted post [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83677/recover-an-accidently-deleted-post).

When I'm composing a post at SO, I've noticed at some point in time there will be a message that appears above the text input box that indicates that a draft has been implicitly saved.

If my computer crashed before I've posted my message, by what process do I recover the draft so that I might complete it and post it?

1. meta SO article 67163 [How do I delete the draft posting? [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67163/how-do-i-delete-the-draft-posting) shows how to empty the *draft buffer* but not how to locate it.
2. meta SO article 67163 also has a scary comment:  *"You only get one draft (if you start answering a new question, old draft is blown a way)"* but does not tell me how to recover the draft that I intend to complete and post.
3. does meta SO also have a draft buffer, and if it does, is it separate from the SO draft buffer?
4. in SO, can I *explicitly* save my drafts?

Comment: There is no explicit mechanism for saving drafts. And to recover it - go back to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It is saved on the question - go back to the question and it will be there in the answer box.
2. See #1 above.
3. Yes, all Stack Exchange sites and meta sites have the exact same mechanism.
4. No. There is no mechanism for that.

Clarification:

The buffer is **per question**.

This is all answered in [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177/140505) - in particular in [the answer by waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/140505) - in particular this:

> If you start answering a particular question, but do not successfully submit, you will see your last saved answer draft the next time you visit *that particular question page*.

Comment: Oded, much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What about draft edits?  After a browser restart, the tab where I had been editing a draft didn't even have the "edit" box open.

Comment: @PeterCordes - no, that's not a a feature. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130071/provide-drafts-on-half-edited-posts

Comment: @Oded: tyvm.  That's exactly what I'm talking about. It didn't come up in my searches that turned up this and other similar questions.  I didn't make a fresh post since I was pretty sure this wouldn't be a new idea. :P